# Access mssql for username created by windows authentication using sqlcmd utility command

Tags: sql-server, linux, active-directory, windows-authentication, remote-server

I am currently trying to connect to mssql from the remote server using sqlcmd utility. The command used:

```
sqlcmd -S <ip> -U my/Username.admin01 -P <password -C
```

However, when I run the sql command, I received following error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'myUsername.admin01'..
```

where it **removed** the **"/"** in my command. As I checked the existing DB, the username my/Username.admin01 is created using **windows authentication**, instead of normal sql server authentication, which I believe windows authentication uses the AD in the domain.

Is there any way to access the mssql using sqlcmd utility for the username created by the windows auth? Thanks.

Comment: The `-U` and `-P` parameters are using SQL Login (username + password) authentication. If you need to login using Windows Authentication then use the `-E` parameter instead. If you need to login using a different user's Windows Authentication then you'll need to use Run-As to open a new Command Prompt using their credentials and run `sqlcmd` from there.

Comment: u mean like. sqlcmd <ip> -E Sqlcmd? But it  gives this output. ( Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SSPI Provider: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KCM:)). Run-As means i need to access to the server where the mssql is located and run the sqlcmd from there? instead of use remote server to access the DB?

Comment: Are you runnning this on a Linux computer, or in a Docker container? The client computer needs to be a member of an Active Directory domain that's trusted by the target server. In the case of Linux computers and Docker containers that means they need to have Kerberos client libraries installed and get joined to a trusted domain.

Comment: I am running on linux server. ah i see, so need the kerberos auth in order to access the mssql. Is it the same case (need kerberos) if I use pyspark or python to connect to mssql db, as this example, instead of bash? ->  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Those examples are using SQL Login authentication with a username and password combination. You can access SQL Server instance from Docker, Linux and macOS computers using SQL Login authentication, but that requires the DBA to have created a SQL Login account on the server and provide you with those credentials. If you want to use Windows Authentication then the container/computer needs to be joined to a trusted domain somehow.

Comment: Yes, you will need to install Kerberos on your Linux machine, and use `kinit` to log in